# Not able to search Element byID

Tags: javascript, html

I am a newbie with javascript and HTML.
I am looking for an element byId and do some operation on it but I am making some trivial mistake somewhere. I have spent a lot of time already on it.

Here is my code -

HTML

```
<body>


          <p>
            <select name="Select Flow" id="Flow" >          
              <option id="option0" value="https://www.google.com">Send Money</option>
              <option id="option1" value="option1"> Money</option>
              <option id="option2" value="option2">Money Service</option>
              <option id="option3" value="option3">XYZ</option>
              <option id="option4" value="option4">XYZ Services</option>
              <option id="option5">No Service</option>
              <option id="option6">ABC waste</option>
              <option id="option7">ABC</option>
              <option id="option8" value="option8">Experiment</option>           
            </select>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="myfunc()"action="" />

        <input type="submit" name="Contribute" id="Contribute" value="Contribute"/>
      </p>
```

JS-

```
function myfunc()
{
document.write("Hello");
var t = document.getElementById("Flow");

if(t)
{
alert(t.innerHTML);
}
}
```

Comment: Yes in Submit button.

Comment: Use console.log() for debugging!!! Forget that document.write exists, why do people teach that anymore!

Comment: I am learning online. Any better links other than W3Schools ?

Comment: Like the answer below says, you're replacing the DOM with `"hello"`. The proper uses for `document.write` are very specific and rare. *If* it's used, it should be only while the page is loading, not after it's already loaded.

Comment: ...don't "forget that it exists". Rather learn how it works. You'll find that it's almost never needed, but can be useful for some very specific cases.

Comment: @R11G: Plenty.  W3Schools (which has no relation to W3C) is not a very good source.  For JavaScript documentation, I suggest Mozilla's docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript  For JavaScript tutorials, try: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript

Comment: @epascarello If I want to intersperse print statements how do I do that?

Comment: @R11G: For debugging?  Use `console.log()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console).

Comment: If you are starting, why not something like http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript

Comment: I also like http://www.htmldog.com/guides/javascript/

Answer (score 7):

`document.write("Hello");` -- this is overwriting your entire DOM, so the next line: `var t = document.getElementById("Flow");` gets no elements, because they don't exist anymore!